# Safari/WebKit percentage values in 'top' property?

Tags: css, safari

I want to relatively position an anchor within a list item with a percentage value.

I'm attempting to do this with this design: http://bit.ly/1awA1Hh

It currently works in FF, Chrome, and IE, but not **Safari/WebKit**.

I've included a fiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish. It seems to work with WebKit, so I'm missing something on the site.

It doesn't make sense to me that any parent elements on the site would interfere with the positioning...

Anyone mind giving it a quick look?

Site: http://bit.ly/1awA1Hh
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7Juf/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="">Hello, World!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Hello, World!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Hello, World!</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li a {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  height: 20%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When you say the fiddle works, what is it supposed to look like exactly? I don't see any evidence of the block being moved from its original position. Nor that the fiddle is supposed to be like the website, for that matter. Edit: oh wait, it's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7Juf/1/

Comment: 'a' tags should be pushed down 60% of the height of the containing 'li'. For Safari: It works in the fiddle, but I'm missing something on the site.

Comment: Positioning looks the same here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qhx4O.jpg Chrome screenshot with inverted Safari screenshot overlaid on it. The only difference is the size/position of the background image (possibly due to window widths).

Comment: Thanks for checking, Scott. Nice technique to compare. I just checked with my Windows version of Safari 5.1.7. And I'm still having the same issues: Unpositioned 'a' and missing image.

Comment: Might be a Windows-Safari-only issue. I'm on a Mac using Safari 6.0.5

Comment: I tested also on a Mac version, and had the same issues. I'll run a browsershot on it. If you can think of any reason why it's not working anyway, let me know.